# C# what is alternative for settings

Tags: c#, class, persistence, settings

I will like to save settings which persist over multiple runs, basically same thing as settings in C# does, when using `Settings.Default.Save()`.

Is there some alternative to store variables in class or something similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a lot of options here.

- Save settings to windows registry.
- Save settings to a text file.
- Save settings in a database.

Here's how I generally go about saving application settings:

- Create a `Settings` class with settings as properties that I want to save.
- Create functions like `LoadSettings()` and `SaveSettings()`.
- `SaveSettings` is responsible for creating an instance of the settings, then serialize it and save it. I use [`Newtonsoft.JSON`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) to serialize into JSON.
- `LoadSettings` reads a file with saved data, deserialize it, and populate the UI with it.

If you implement something similar, you can even save the settings file with a custom file extension and then associate that extension to your application.

This way, in your `main` method, you can check which settings file to load.

I generally use this approach when I have to allow more than one instance of my application because the `<namespace>.Properties.Settings` doesn't cut it in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can store data in many ways.

For example:

1. Application config
2. Object serialization - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx
3. Some other external files like XML, Json - 
   http://www.w3.org/XML/
   http://json.org/
4. Database